# 14.04 - Replaced drive in Software RAID 1 - How to make bootable?

Tags: boot, 14.04, grub2, raid, mdadm

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 x64 server with 2 500GB drives (`sda` and `sdb`) in a software RAID 1.

I just had to replace `sdb`. Adding it back to the array with mdadm and resyncing was a snap. The problem I'm running into is making sure it can boot if `sda` happens to fail in the future.

*Note: all commands below were run as root*

---

### 1st try

Most walkthroughs I've found told me to run:

```
grub-install /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

Which is the exact same command I've seen the Ubuntu installer run a hundred times. However, when I ran that, I got:

```
grub-install: error: More than one install device?.
```

This has always worked for me. Maybe something changed with 14.04?

---

### 2nd try

Some walkthroughs recommended setting up grub for the new hard drive manually. The grub prompt scares me, but I was willing to try these steps:

```
# grub --device-map=/boot/grub/device.map
grub> root (hd0,0)
grub> setup (hd0)
grub> root (hd1,0)
grub> setup (hd1)
grub> quit
```

Only problem? After the first command, I get:

```
The program 'grub' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install grub
```

???

So I tried installing grub.

```
# apt-get install grub
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  grub-legacy-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub2-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  grub
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 913 kB of archives.
After this operation, 438 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Needless to say, I answered no.

---

### 3rd try

Getting desparate, I tried something I was pretty sure was wrong. [The official server](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/advanced-installation.html#raid-maintenance) guide recommends (at the bottom of the "Raid Maintenance" section):

```
grub-install /dev/md0
```

This was the output:

```
# grub-install /dev/md0
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: Couldn't find physical volume `(null)'. Some modules may be missing from core image..
grub-install: warning: Couldn't find physical volume `(null)'. Some modules may be missing from core image..
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

Scary.

---

It looks like grub has been superceded somehow in 14.04, but I can't find any information about how things have changed. I do have a `/boot/grub/` directory, so I know some form of grub is installed.

---

### Update:

I was able to run the following commands independently:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install /dev/sdb
```

However, I'm unsure if `sda` will boot after installing grub on `sdb` and vice versa. Am I ok?

Comment: You could remove one drive at a time and seeing if they boot normally.

Comment: At the moment, I'm not sure either drive will boot (see my last update). I can't just take this server down to test it and (potentially) reload it if it is hosed. There has to be a proper way to do this. I know I'm not the first person who has replaced a bootable RAID1 drive in Ubuntu 14.04 (maybe just the most ignorant).

Comment: [Apologies if this doesn't help] When I configured my Ubuntu raid-1 server I found I couldn't put my boot partitions on on the raid volume. I assumed this was because I couldn't access software raid until the kernel is loaded - i.e. post boot. I created two small boot partitions - one on each drive - and duplicated the boot partition between the physical disks using dd. I can now boot from either drive... as they have identical boot partitions.

Comment: Your are Ok just now mount your `/dev/sdb` partition and run `update-grub` in it. this answer might help you http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/283843

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. The way to make sure GRUB is properly installed on and recognizes both drives from each is to run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

When prompted which drives to install on, make sure all boot drives are selected. In my case, this was `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. Do not select `/dev/md0` or any of the other `md` devices.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: I needed to add a delay script to my boot configuration to allow a degraded RAID array enough time to assemble. Otherwise everything worked fine when booting with 2 working drives, but as soon as I disconnected one drive to test the redundancy I ended up in busybox (without keyboard for good measure)! For details, see the end of step 6 in [How to install Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with a dual-boot RAID 1 partition on an UEFI/GPT system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an-uefi) (the part about /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/sleepAwhile).